# How can I isolate specific string patterns from this body of text

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have the following file:
[2013-07-17_19-12-42.dcrec](http://akegroup.org/defcon/recordings/4/2013-07-17_19-12-42.dcrec)

How can I search for and isolate the following string pattern in the file:

New name for client 0, keyID = 000000, IP = 000.000.000.000 : somename

The client # could be any number, the keyid is any numerical value (there is not a set length for the client # or keyID), the IP is any normal IPv4 address and somename would be any username (the username can include special characters such as #, ^, @, spaces, etc). It looks like the string is 'closed' with a '^Bvs'. Here is an example of two of the strings (see screenshots)

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

There can be any number of these strings in each file(s). If I could search for and list all instances of these strings in the file(s) that would be great. Im not too good with grep, etc at the moment or else I would be able to do this on my own. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Those screenshots are a tad hard to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$> strings 2013-07-17_19-12-42.dcrec | grep -o -P "New name for client [0-9]+, keyID = [0-9]+, IP = [0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3} : [^\ ]+"                          
New name for client 7, keyID = 562830, IP = 91.193.208.105 : Sobieski
New name for client 8, keyID = 255344, IP = 63.153.210.124 : Cultist
New name for client 11, keyID = 5061431, IP = 116.240.255.94 : Sammy
New name for client 12, keyID = 5061453, IP = 196.20.195.114 : Dirk
New name for client 13, keyID = 4278381, IP = 188.110.185.183 : CSTO
New name for client 14, keyID = 369397, IP = 81.110.45.165 : General
New name for client 16, keyID = 5061651, IP = 85.4.29.162 : Thatsuseless
New name for client 17, keyID = 5061688, IP = 90.213.51.77 : NewPlayer
New name for client 18, keyID = 4905930, IP = 174.109.181.108 : Solo
New name for client 19, keyID = 5061695, IP = 85.4.236.70 : Quizzman
New name for client 21, keyID = 2745089, IP = 95.128.68.231 : NewPlayer
New name for client 22, keyID = 5061536, IP = 195.91.236.65 : POWERFUCKER
New name for client 24, keyID = 5061698, IP = 86.121.66.142 : TheDoctor
New name for client 26, keyID = 5061585, IP = 5.69.250.33 : Hydrogen
```

Explanations:

- if input file is in binary format it could be processed by `strings` to retrieve all text;
- *The client # could be any number* : `[0-9]+`
- *the keyid is any numerical value* : `[0-9]+`
- *the IP is any normal IPv4 address* : `[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}`
- *somename would be any username (the username can include special characters such as #, ^, @, spaces, etc)* : `[^\ ]+` which means "no spaces"

Seems to be enough for the first time. Yep, all these regexps could be improved.

UPD: actually, it looks better with `.*` regex for the last field (somename)

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply, thanks for your help though! This had done the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
grep --binary-files=text -o 'New name for client[^^B]*' 2013-07-17_19-12-42.dcrec
```

The `[^^B]*` part is regular `[^` followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and regular `]`, which means any character that is not the `^B` control character.

*Output*:

```
New name for client 7, keyID = 562830, IP = 91.193.208.105 : Sobieski
New name for client 8, keyID = 255344, IP = 63.153.210.124 : Cultist O Khorne
New name for client 11, keyID = 5061431, IP = 116.240.255.94 : Sammy
New name for client 12, keyID = 5061453, IP = 196.20.195.114 : Dirk Diggler
New name for client 13, keyID = 4278381, IP = 188.110.185.183 : CSTO
New name for client 14, keyID = 369397, IP = 81.110.45.165 : General Ivan
New name for client 16, keyID = 5061651, IP = 85.4.29.162 : Thatsuseless
New name for client 17, keyID = 5061688, IP = 90.213.51.77 : NewPlayer
New name for client 17 (NewPlayer), keyID = 5061688, IP = 90.213.51.77 : MHT
New name for client 18, keyID = 4905930, IP = 174.109.181.108 : Solo Wing Pixy
New name for client 19, keyID = 5061695, IP = 85.4.236.70 : Quizzman
New name for client 21, keyID = 2745089, IP = 95.128.68.231 : NewPlayer
New name for client 18 (Solo Wing Pixy), keyID = 4905930, IP = 174.109.181.108 : Jane The Killer
New name for client 22, keyID = 5061536, IP = 195.91.236.65 : POWERFUCKER
New name for client 24, keyID = 5061698, IP = 86.121.66.142 : TheDoctor
New name for client 26, keyID = 5061585, IP = 5.69.250.33 : Hydrogen
```

If you want to filter out the rows like:

```
New name for client 17 (NewPlayer), keyID = 5061688, IP = 90.213.51.77 : MHT
New name for client 18 (Solo Wing Pixy), keyID = 4905930, IP = 174.109.181.108 : Jane The Killer
```

use a variation of the above:

```
grep --binary-files=text -o 'New name for client [0-9]\+,[^^B]*' \
   2013-07-17_19-12-42.dcrec
```